# shuffling `li` elements within a `ul`

Tags: jquery

I want to shuffle `li` elements within a `ul` - and I found [this working code](http://jsfiddle.net/8q9JQ/1/). I just don't understand how it is replacing elements 'in place' instead of adding them to the end of the existing array.

```
var list = $('ul');
var count = $('ul li').length;
for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
  $('li', list).eq(j).appendTo(list);
}
```

What behavior of `.eq()` or `.appendTo()` am I overlooking in the docs that makes this possible? Thanks!

Comment: `.eq(j)` selects `j` element from selection, `appendTo` moves it to the end of the `list` element (re-appends as the last child).

Comment: From jQuery docs : "If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned) and a new set consisting of the inserted element is returned" http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/